# Add IFCONFIG in config.xml

Tags: configuration

I have a requirement where I need to add my custom discount block only if the discount module is enabled from backend. I can obviously add it in using getStoreConfig() values, but I need to know is it possible to add **IFCONFIG** in our modules **etc/config.xml** file ?

Below is my sample config.xml file code but somehow its not working.

```
<global>
    <sales>
          <quote>
                <totals>
                    <testing ifconfig="mysettings/foo/sayhello"> 
                        <class>NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Testing</class>
                        <after>subtotal</after>
                    </testing>
                </totals>
            </quote>
     </sales>
</global>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ifconfig` attribute only works in certain layout XML definitions, not in config XML files

**You would have to go with your idea of checking with `getStoreConfig()` in your custom class.**

It is possible to inject custom XML values conditionally at run-time, but there is no good place for it at the moment so the best idea would be to override the core config model and pass your own version into the bootstrapper in index.php (meaning this also has to be done for all shell/external scripts)

When we're on the subject of quote totals and the `<after>` tag, make sure you don't have any other third party modules or admin settings that modify the sort order and gives you unexpected results. You might need to specify `<before>` as well, together with multiple comma-separated totals codes in both.

Comment: You mean I can do ifconfig in layout files but not in config.xml or system.xml files

Comment: Exactly, but it only works for <action> definitions in layout XML files, see: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L292

Comment: Yes ifconfig only works for action element